# Solve initial value problem 1st order DE.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

ive been struggling to solve the following equation.

$t^3 \frac{dx}{dt}  +  3*t^2 x   =   t$

I tried to use its characteristic equation and got the one root for $x$ must be $Ae^{-3t/x}$ but i just end up confusing myself even more. I read that you can do it by separating the variables but im not sure if this is possible in this case. Could anyone help me out? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{d}{dt}(t^3x(t))=t^{3}\frac{dx}{dt}+3t^2x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$t^3 \frac{dx}{dt}  +  3*t^2 x   =   t$

$ \frac{dx}{dt}  +  3\frac1t x   =   \frac1{t^2}$

$ \frac{dx}{dt}     =   \frac1{t^2}-3*\frac1t x$

thus, the equation is not separable, but note that

$\frac{d}{dx}\{t^3  x\}=   t^3 \frac{dx}{dt}  +  3t^2 x   =   t$

thus
$t^3  x= \int  t dt = \frac12 t^2 +C$

or 
$x(t)= \frac1{2t} + \frac {C}{t^3}$

Answer (score 1):

now this equation can be reduced to (dx\dt)+(3\t)x=1\t^2
using method of integrating factors 
define afunction of t μ(t) 
multiplying by μ

(dx\dt)μ  +(3\t)xμ =1\t^2μ 
and suppose d\dt(μ x)=to the left side of equation ( and as result to the right)
we will have 
(dμ \dt)x=(3\t)xμ 
dμ \μ =3dt\t
by itegrating
 μ =at^3
now d\dt(xt^3)=t ( by comparing d\dt(μ x) with the right side and substituting by μ)
by integrating the right side 
x(at^3)=(at^2)\2+c
x=(1\2t) + C\t^3

Comment: actually μ can be t^3 by the hint instead of comparing and integrating